# How do I read .csv files on my S6?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

When I try to open the file to an editor I get a blank document.  What do I need to read a .csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an Microsoft office subscription I would install Microsoft excel. Otherwise Google Sheets